# Accessing a NSMutableArray from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` and I need to access it from another class. This is what I have done so far;

1. I declared `NSMutableArray *muArr` in the `.h` file, and `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *muArr`.
2. `@synthasize muArr;` in the `.m` file, and finally populated it:

   `[muArr addObject: @"First"];`
3. Now in `SecondView` I added the import statement `#import "FirstView.h"` and wrote: `FirstView *frv = [[FirstView alloc]init];` then `NSLog(@"%i",[frv.muArr count]);`

These lines of code are written in the `viewDidLoad` method. and when the `NSLog` was printed I got `0` records instead of `1`.

Why is this? what have I done wrong, and can someone show me a sample code/tutorial?

Comment: In which method do you populate the muArr (where is the addObject: call)?

Comment: I wrote it inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, so when the user clicks on the cell/row. this method gets executed, and the `muArr` gets populated.

Comment: Did you ever actually create the NSMutableArray??  I don't see a statement to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are populating `muArr` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, which doesn't get called until you select a row. By calling `init` on your FirstView, you create a new FirstView then immediately check the count of `muArr`. The count is 0, because you haven't selected any rows yet..

Comment: Its like this, when i click on a row, `muArr` gets populated, and the page will get redirected to `FirstView`, so there i need to access `muArr` and get its count.

Comment: You mean it gets redirected to `SecondView`? Your steps are like (1) FirstView loads up, (2) user clicks on a row, (3) second view loads up and you need to check value of an array of FirstView. If that's the case, you need to pass a reference of the `FirstView` to the SecondView -- You are creating a new, different FirstView by using `alloc` and `init`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a property(in the same fashion as you create muArr) in SecondView class

Step 1) : Lets say arrOfSecondView  and you synthesize it

Step 2) Now you can add your muArr data to arrOfSecondView

```
   SecondView *secondView = [[SecondView alloc]init];
   secondView .arrOfFirstView = muArr;
   //and i guess you are pushing to secondView controller
```

Step 3) Check the arrOfFirstView count

Comment: Why do i have to do this, isn't it the same as accessing `muArr` directly ? If `muArr` return a count of `0`, won't `arrOfFirstView` return `0` ?

Comment: NO, how can be muArr will be zero because you are initializing and adding the object in first view and want to use in second view.

Answer (score 0):

Do you allocate the array? Before you add items to it, you have to allocate it with

```
myArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If you don't do that, the [addObject] call will not crash the program, but won't have any effect. And array's `count` will remain zero forever.

@synthesize, contrary to a popular belief, does not allocate the ivar. It just generates a getter method and, optionally, a setter method in the class.

Comment: Yes, i did allocate the array and then only i populated it with values